# Colouring text in a notification message created by AppleScript

Tags: applescript, notifications

The followng AppleScript code shows a notification message with the texts **Text A** and **Text B** both in black.

```
display notification "Test B" with title "Text A"
```

Is it possible to set their colour to, say red and blue each?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the AppleScript Language Guide Command Reference for [`display notification`](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_cmds.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH216-SW224), none of it's Parameters mention any color attributes for the *text*, and therefore I'd have to say the answer is no.